# Center mobile toggle icon in Foundation 5

Tags: menu, icons, toggle, zurb-foundation

I am trying to center the toggle menu icon on mobile in Foundation 5. I added in this:

```
.top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon {
padding:0px 0 0 0;
right:50%;
}
```

But it is obviously a bit off due to the size of the icon itself. I can't seem to figure out how to get it right in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
padding:0;
right:50%;
margin-right:-36px;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
.top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon {
  padding: 0;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -9px;
}
```